# how to use php or js to record the stay time of user in my web site page?

Tags: javascript, php

how to use php or js to record the stay time of user in my web site page?

someone click a link and jump to my website page, he stay in the page for 5 seconds then close the page. 
I want to record the 5 seconds to my database , how can I do the job using js or php?
it seems as the same as ga, but I don't know how ga do this.

Comment: Why you don't you use a Thrid-party app for control this? Like Google Analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript's setInterval method to periodically send something to your server

For example:

```
setInterval(function(){
    sendToServer()
},1000);
```